# iOS: Max zoom out for MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How can I calculate the max zoom out in MapKit to show the entire globe?

Example:

```
let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -37.8136, longitude: 144.9631), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 170, longitudeDelta: 170))
```

If instead of 170 I put 200 the App crash telling me:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:-37.81360000, +144.96310000 span:+200.00000000, +200.00000000>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing `MKCoordinateRegion` with coordinate and span and use `MKMapView.setRegion(_ region: MKCoordinateRegion, animated: Bool)`

> Changing just the center coordinate of the region can still cause the span values to change implicitly. The span values might change because the distances represented by a span change at different latitudes and longitudes and the map view may need to adjust the span to account for the new location

Ref: [MKMapView.setRegion(_ region: MKCoordinateRegion, animated: Bool)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452768-setregion)

Here is my workaround with `MKMapCamera`.

Code in MapScreen.swift

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover // Change to satellite mode
        // Or you can use .satelliteFlyover
    
        // We delay update by 1 second to get final size of mapView on UI.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
            self.focusOnPointAndShowGlobe()
        }
    }
    
    func focusOnPointAndShowGlobe() {
        let mapHeight = mapView.bounds.height // the constraint of visible Map area will base on HEIGHT of mapview

        // These are standard/base value from adjustment
        let standardMapHeight: CGFloat = 450
        let standardCameraDistance: CGFloat = 24 * 1000 * 1000 // 24,000 km
        
        let targetDistance = (mapHeight / standardMapHeight) * standardCameraDistance
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -37.8136, longitude: 144.9631)
        let camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: center, fromDistance: targetDistance, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
        self.mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
    }
}
```

MapView layout in Xib (I'm using fullscreen layout)

[image]

This is result on Portrait mode, `focusOnPointAndShowGlobe()` will focus on center location then move away from the Earth to disply entire globe, when you open this screen or call `focusOnPointAndShowGlobe()` again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Earth has 2 hemispheres, divided into 90 degrees each. So latitude range is from -90 to 90 i.e. `latitudeDelta` cannot be more than 180 degrees.

Longitude range is from -180 to 180, so `longitudeDelta` max is 360 degrees.

To show a globe, set `MapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover` or `MapView.mapType = .satelliteFlyover`.